# Unable to connect Godaddy domain with route 53 elastic ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am trying to connect my `EC2` elastic ip with one of my domains on `Godaddy` but it refused to connect after a long time. in my `Route53` I have created hosted zone for my domain name and copied the NameSpaces to my godaddy DNS management but it didnt worked.

**Route53**
[image: route53]

**Godaddy**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

DNS takes some time to propagate across all networks. Give it some time and it will be resolved. In fact, I can see it has resolved for me and will be resolved for you as well soon.

Comment: yeah your are right but its\ been more than 15 hours so i was bit curious

Answer (score 1):

DNS propagation may take time. Login to your instance and try resolving the domain. Use the command, `nslookup ghumphirlo.com`